# Appending two different queries- Business objects Universe

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have built two queries using two different Universe. One Universe will give me data for the year 2015 and another data will give data for 2016.

Our fiscal calendar for 2015 ( October 2014 to September 2015). Hence I have the complete data for the year 2015 in one "Universe" .

For the year 2016 I will get the data from another Universe, which will get refreshed everyday.

I am doing an analysis where I need to compare the 2015 and 2016 data together.

Experts, please let me know if there is way to append 2015 and 2016 data using queries created by two different universe.

The data for 2015 remains constant, the data for 2016 should get append as soon its refreshed. Please advise if there is a way to append this data.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Is this a WebI or DeskI report?  Also, can you not use a single data provider but include fiscal year dimension object to create a pivoted table?  This is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge these two queries, similar to a SQL Union, even if they're based on the same data source.

On the report level, highlight and right-click the dimensions that are the same (date --> date, id --> id) and merge them individually.

Measures cannot be merged, but you can create an overall variable to add them together. Right-click on the 'variables' folder on the side, and type in a formula for a measure, like so:

```
=[Domestic].[Revenue] + [International].Revenue
```

Then, just drag and drop your data objects (merged dimensions and variable measures) onto your report.

This is assuming you're using WEBI.